# Dressing someone else's cut

Tags: vocabulary

From https://wikitravel.org/en/Botswana#Stay_healthy :

> Botswana's HIV infection rate, estimated at 24.1%, is the 2nd highest
>   reported in the world. Exercise regular universal precautions when
>   dealing with any bodily fluid and remain aware of this high rate of
>   infection. Take precautions accordingly. **Wear rubber gloves when
>   dressing someone else's cut**, even if they are a child.

Does "to dress a cut" mean "to treat a skin wound"? Is this phrase common in other regions or is it specific to Southern Africa?

Comment: That's exactly what it means. To "dress" a wound means to apply bandages to it (after cleaning and suturing, if necessary).

Comment: It's common everywhere. He's cleaning out the wound and then bandaging it, i.e. he's dressing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [dressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dressing_(medical)) (noun) is a usually-sterile bandage or gauze used to cover a skin wound.  "To dress a wound" means to treat a wound with a dressing.

*To dress [a wound]* is used throughout the English-speaking world, especially in first aid manuals and similar quasi-technical resources.  A more everyday equivalent, at least in American English, would be *to clean and bandage [a wound]*.